# Process logfile to identify stalled data creation

Tags: perl

I have some processes running that create data at different rates. I'd like to use perl to identify those experiments that have not created data for more than 1 hour in order to terminate them early. The log file looks more or less like this (generated every 15 minutes, shortened for legibility):

```
# Dataset,Timestamp,dataset size
exp-201905040115a,1556932502,0
exp-201905040115b,1556932502,0
exp-201905040115a,1556934301,213906
exp-201905040115b,1556934301,25487
exp-201905040115a,1556936102,399950
exp-201905040115b,1556936102,210548
exp-201905040115a,1556937002,399950
exp-201905040115b,1556937002,487250
exp-201905040115a,1556937902,399950
exp-201905040115b,1556937902,487250
exp-201905040115a,1556938802,399950
exp-201905040115b,1556938802,502145
exp-201905040115a,1556939701,399950
exp-201905040115b,1556939701,502145
exp-201905040115a,1556940601,399950
exp-201905040115b,1556940601,502145
exp-201905040115a,1556941502,399950
exp-201905040115b,1556941502,502145
exp-201905040115a,1556942401,399950
exp-201905040115b,1556942401,502145
```

The first dataset size is usually 0, but sometimes a small number (<100).

I've already learned how to read the data from the logfile and check it line by line (or perhaps turn that line into an array to extract the column entries).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @datasets = ( 'exp-201905040115a', 'exp-201905040115b' );

foreach my $dataset (@datasets) {
        open my $logfile, '<', 'data.log' or die "Cannot open: $!";
        while (my $line = <$logfile>) {
                chomp $line;
                my ( $log_dataset, $log_timestamp, $log_datasize ) = split /,/, $line ;

                if ( $dataset eq $log_dataset ) {
                        print "Matched: " , $dataset, "\t" ;
                        printf('%10d', $log_datasize) ;
                        print " at " , $log_timestamp , "\n" ;
                }
        }
        close $logfile;
}
```

1. I'm a bit stumped though how to go about the part that tells me if any change has occurred in the third column within the last 3600 seconds. I guess I have to compare values from the various lines against each other, but here are so many to compare?
2. Also, is there a more efficient way than going over the entire logfile several times (once for each dataset)?

Can anyone give me a suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Is that header in your actual data file?

Answer (score 1):

The CSV input and multiple datasets to group by make me think of databases. And indeed...

```sh
#!/bin/sh
logfile="$1"
sqlite3 -batch -noheader -csv <<EOF
CREATE TABLE logs(dataset TEXT, ts INTEGER, size INTEGER
                , PRIMARY KEY(dataset, size, ts)) WITHOUT ROWID;
.import "$logfile" logs
SELECT dataset
FROM logs AS l
GROUP BY dataset, size
HAVING max(ts) - min(ts) >= 3600
   AND max(ts) = (SELECT max(ts) FROM logs AS l2 WHERE l.dataset = l2.dataset
                                                   AND l.size = l2.size)
ORDER BY dataset;
EOF
```

will print out `exp-201905040115a` when run on your sample data.

But you want perl. There is a handy [driver](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::CSV) for DBI that works with CSV files, but the SQL dialect it supports doesn't include `HAVING` plus it's pretty slow. So, plan b.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;

my %datasets;

# Read the log file into a hash table of lists of (time,size) pairs.
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my ($ds, $time, $size) = split /,/;
  push @{$datasets{$ds}}, [ $time => $size ];
}

# For each dataset listed in the file:
DATASET:
while (my ($ds, $data) = each %datasets) {
  # Sort list in reverse order of time
  @$data = sort { $b->[0] <=> $a->[0] } @$data;
  # Get the most recent entry
  my ($time, $size) = @{shift @$data};
  # And compare it against the rest until...
  for my $rec (@$data) {
    # ... different size
    next DATASET if $size != $rec->[1];
    # ... Same size, entry more than an hour old
    if ($time - $rec->[0] >= 3600) {
      say $ds;
      next DATASET;
    }
  }
}
```